# Hangfire - Recurring job can’t be scheduled, see inner exception for details

Tags: hangfire

I have an app; which is live on three different servers, using a loadbalancer for user distribution.
The app uses its own queue and I have added a filter for jobs to keep their `original` queue in case they fail at some point. But then again, it continues to act like the app is not running. The error is like below;

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Recurring job can't be scheduled, see inner exception for details.
 ---> Hangfire.Common.JobLoadException: Could not load the job. See inner exception for the details.
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not resolve assembly 'My.Api'.
   at System.TypeNameParser.ResolveAssembly(String asmName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Boolean throwOnError, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.TypeNameParser.ConstructType(Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.TypeNameParser.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError)
   at Hangfire.Common.TypeHelper.DefaultTypeResolver(String typeName)
   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()
   at Hangfire.RecurringJobEntity..ctor(String recurringJobId, IDictionary`2 recurringJob, ITimeZoneResolver timeZoneResolver, DateTime now)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Hangfire.Server.RecurringJobScheduler.ScheduleRecurringJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String recurringJobId, RecurringJobEntity recurringJob, DateTime now)
What can be the issue here? The apps are running. And once I trigger the recurring jobs, they are good to go, until they show the above error.
```

This is my AppStart file;

```
private IEnumerable<IDisposable> GetHangfireServers()
{
    Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
        .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
        .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
        .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
        .UseSqlServerStorage(HangfireServer, new SqlServerStorageOptions
        {
            CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
            UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
            DisableGlobalLocks = true
        });

    yield return new BackgroundJobServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions {
        Queues = new[] { "myapp" + GetEnvironmentName() },
        ServerName = "MyApp" + ConfigurationHelper.GetAppSetting("Environment")
    });
}

public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();
    
    RegisterTaskDependencies(container);
    container.RegisterWebApiControllers(System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    container.Verify();
    
    var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
    configuration.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    
    /* HANGFIRE CONFIGURATION */
    if (Environment == "Production")
    {
        GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new PreserveOriginalQueueAttribute());
        Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(new SimpleInjectorJobActivator(container));
        Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseLogProvider(new Api.HangfireArea.Helpers.CustomLogProvider(container.GetInstance<Core.Modules.LogModule>()));
        app.UseHangfireAspNet(GetHangfireServers);
        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
        {
            Authorization = new[] { new DashboardAuthorization() },
            AppPath = GetBackToSiteURL(),
            DisplayStorageConnectionString = false
        });
        AddOrUpdateJobs();
    }
    /* HANGFIRE CONFIGURATION */
    
    app.UseWebApi(configuration);
    
    WebApiConfig.Register(configuration);

}

public static void AddOrUpdateJobs()
{
    var queueName = "myapp" + GetEnvironmentName();
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<HangfireArea.BackgroundJobs.AttachmentCreator>(
         "MyApp_MyTask",
         (service) => service.RunMyTask(), 
      "* * * * *", queue: queueName, timeZone: TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Turkey Standard Time"));
}
```

What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out, Hangfire itself does not work great when multiple apps use the same `sql schema`. To solve this problem I used [Hangfire.MAMQSqlExtension](https://github.com/GeXiaoguo/Hangfire.MAMQSqlExtension). It is a third-party extension but the repo says that it is officially recognized by Hangfire.
If you are using the same schema for multiple apps, you **have to** use this extension in **all** your apps, otherwise you'll face the error mentioned above.

If your apps have different versions alive at the same time (e.g. *production*, *test*, *development*) this app itself does not fully work for **failed jobs**. If a job fails, regular Hangfire will not respect it's original queue, hence will move it to the `default` queue. Which will eventually create problems if your app only works with your app's queue or if the `default` queue is shared. To solve that issue, to force Hangfire to respect the original queue attribute, I used [this](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/pull/502#issuecomment-176744750) solution. Which works great, and you get to name your app's queue depending on your `web.config` or `appsettings.json`.

My previous answer was deleted for some reason? This solves the problem and there's no other way. Do not delete the answer, for people who will experience this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another option I found was to use Hangfire's background process https://www.hangfire.io/overview.html#background-process.

```
public class CleanTempDirectoryProcess : IBackgroundProcess
{
    public void Execute(BackgroundProcessContext context)
    {
        Directory.CleanUp(Directory.GetTempDirectory());
        context.Wait(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
    }
}
```

And set the delay. This solved the issue for me as I need to the job to run repeatedly. I'm not sure of the implications this might have with the dashboard.

Comment: I guess this error happens in different scenarios as my problem was about running multiple apps via the same database schema. If your solution helps with that, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Job Filters that will do the same as Retry by placing the Queue.

The difference is that you cannot wait to run the job. It will run immediately.

```
public class AutomaticRetryQueueAttribute : JobFilterAttribute, IApplyStateFilter, IElectStateFilter
{
    private string queue;
    private int attempts;
    private readonly object _lockObject = new object();

    private readonly ILog _logger = LogProvider.For<AutomaticRetryQueueAttribute>();

    public AutomaticRetryQueueAttribute(int Attempts = 10, string Queue = "Default")
    {
        queue = Queue;
        attempts = Attempts;
    }

    public int Attempts
    {
        get { lock (_lockObject) { return attempts; } }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), @"Attempts value must be equal or greater than zero.");
            }

            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                attempts = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public string Queue
    {
        get { lock (_lockObject) { return queue; } }
        set
        {
            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                queue = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnStateApplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
    {
        var newState = context.NewState as EnqueuedState;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queue) && newState != null && newState.Queue != Queue)
        {
            newState.Queue = String.Format(Queue, context.BackgroundJob.Job.Args.ToArray());
        }

        if ((context.NewState is ScheduledState || context.NewState is EnqueuedState) &&
            context.NewState.Reason != null &&
            context.NewState.Reason.StartsWith("Retry attempt"))
        {
            transaction.AddToSet("retries", context.BackgroundJob.Id);
        }
    }

    public void OnStateUnapplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
    {
        if (context.OldStateName == ScheduledState.StateName)
        {
            transaction.RemoveFromSet("retries", context.BackgroundJob.Id);
        }
    }

    public void OnStateElection(ElectStateContext context)
    {
        var failedState = context.CandidateState as FailedState;
        if (failedState == null)
        {
            // This filter accepts only failed job state.
            return;
        }

        var retryAttempt = context.GetJobParameter<int>("RetryCount") + 1;

        if (retryAttempt <= Attempts)
        {
            ScheduleAgainLater(context, retryAttempt, failedState);
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.ErrorException($"Failed to process the job '{context.BackgroundJob.Id}': an exception occurred.", failedState.Exception);
        }
    }

    private void ScheduleAgainLater(ElectStateContext context, int retryAttempt, FailedState failedState)
    {
        context.SetJobParameter("RetryCount", retryAttempt);

        const int maxMessageLength = 50;
        var exceptionMessage = failedState.Exception.Message.Length > maxMessageLength
            ? failedState.Exception.Message.Substring(0, maxMessageLength - 1) + "…"
            : failedState.Exception.Message;

        // If attempt number is less than max attempts, we should
        // schedule the job to run again later.

        var reason = $"Retry attempt {retryAttempt} of {Attempts}: {exceptionMessage}";

        context.CandidateState = (IState)new EnqueuedState { Reason = reason };

        if (context.CandidateState is EnqueuedState enqueuedState)
        {
            enqueuedState.Queue = String.Format(Queue, context.BackgroundJob.Job.Args.ToArray());
        }

        _logger.WarnException($"Failed to process the job '{context.BackgroundJob.Id}': an exception occurred. Retry attempt {retryAttempt} of {Attempts} will be performed.", failedState.Exception);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Detele the old hangfire data base and recreate the db with new name
2. Or Use in Memory strorage method (UseInMemoryStorage)